# Why we need NATIVESDK in yocto?

Tags: linux, sdk, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

In lot of recipes variable `BBCLASSEXTEND` is used. Mostly used arguments for this variable is `native` and nativesdk`. I see the purpose of native is to compile the recipes. For example` cmake-native/3.6.1-r0/sysroot-destdir/`points to`build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/cmake` , so this binary is been used in recipes which uses cmake to compile (correct me if I'm wrong). Now my question is why we need NATIVESDK in recipe. What is the purpose of NATIVESDK.

Can anyone please explain.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This simply adds the package to the native SDK: https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Technical_FAQ#What_does_.22nativesdk.22_mean.3F

> The "nativesdk" prefix identifies recipes (and variants of recipes) that produce files intended for the host portion of the standard SDK, or for things which are constructed like an SDK such as buildtools-tarball. These are built for SDKMACHINE which may or may not be the same architecture as the build host.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, I have a recipe without native and native sdk, and when I built the sdk with populate_sdk the static library provided by the recipe was added to sdk. So what does adding the native and nativesdk to recipe actually change?